# Stalelement exception in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I am using Selenium via Java.

I am running into a stale element exception and I can't seem to identify the issue.

I am interacting with a carousel (see image below). I have placed all the vehicles, in the carousel, into a list and I am trying to get the text back from each webelement in the list. The list contains eight elements. When my code interacts with the last page of the carousel (in this case the sixth index of the list) a stale element exception gets thrown.

Here is the code where I placed all the vehicles in the carousel in a list:

```
List<WebElement> vehiclesInCarousel = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div[data-qaid='cntnr-frntlnlstng-carousel'] ul[class='slider-list'] li[class='slider-slide']"));
```

[image]

Comment: It's difficult to find root cause without debugging. However, I usually solve this be getting element one by one instead of get multiple elements. First, count the vehicles then use ":nth-child" to get an item, then test it one by one.

Comment: @Buaban It happens at index six which happens to be the third page of the carousel. Every element prior to index six works as expected but when I try to access index six or beyond I get a stale element exception.

Comment: the sixth element List<WebElement> in might be changed because you perform somethings on the application. That't why I suggest getting element and perform action one by one instead of storing them in the List.

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML and code that you are using to navigate the list, etc. Can you post a link to the page?

Answer (score 0):

A stale element reference exception is thrown in one of two cases:

1. The element has been deleted entirely.
2. The element is no longer attached to the DOM.

Yes there is a possibility that element which you are looking for is visible but you see StaleElementException just because of above 2 reasons (mainly).

How to deal with it see [this](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.jsp)